# Discord make channel using bot

Tags: javascript, discord

I'm making a discord bot, and I'm trying to make use of the createChannel function shown [here](http://discordjs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs_client.html#createchannel-server-name-type-callback) in the documentation. For some reason, I am getting the following error:

TypeError: bot.createChannel is not a function.

My code is within a function which I pass a message to, and I have been able to create roles and add users to roles within the same function. It's just the createChannel function that's not working. Below is the relevant portions of the code.

```
const bot = new Discord.Client();

function makeChannel(message){
    var server = message.guild;
    var name = message.author.username;

    server.createRole(data);
    var newrole = server.roles.find("name", name);
    message.author.addrole(newrole);

    /* The above 3 lines all work perfectly */


    bot.createChannel(server,name);
}
```

I have also tried bot.addChannel, and bot.ChannelCreate, since ChannelCreate.js is the name of the file which contains the code for this command. Also, I have attempted specifying channel type and assigning a callback function as well, but the main issue is the TypeError saying that this isn't a function at all. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Additionally, I plan to use ServerChannel.update() at some point in the future, so any advice on getting that to work once the previous problem is resolved would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does `bot` contain any methods? Try `console.log(bot)` and check output. Maybe there is something wrong with `Client` class.

Comment: The bot is a client, and you try to create channel from the client ? Maybe try create channel from the server constant

Comment: @CyrilBeeckman Why not? Client can create channels, did you even check docs before commenting?

Comment: @Oen44 I don't know how it works but if client can make chan, it should be allowed to create channel no ? Same like TeamSpeak or others

Comment: Have you logged in as the bot? `bot.login('mybot@example.com', 'password', some_function);`

Comment: I tried the console.log(bot) idea, and I don't see any methods in the console, but it also seems like half of the log got chopped off because the entry was so long. I can only scroll up so far into the console's history.

Comment: Can you see any of the methods mentioned in the docs though? It might be that this method is no longer supported but who knows...

Comment: Ok, my console is now showing the entirety of the console.log(bot), and there are 2 things that I think might be related to the method. First, there is a value "actions" which appears to be a JSON object titled ActionsManager. Within this object, there is a value ChannelCreate: ChannelCreateAction { client: [circular]}. ChannelCreate is the name of one of the .js files that comes with the Discord.js package. Second, there is a value called methods within the value rest: RESTManager{}, and it has a value of methods: RESTMethods{ rest: [circular], client: [circular]}.

Comment: Not sure if any of that helps, but it does seem like the bot has the code for the method within it, since it has the ChannelCreate value for the ChannelCreate.js file

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Alright, after a few days of trying things and going through the docs, I have discovered the solution. I am using a more recent version of Discord than the docs I was reading were written for. In the newer version, channels are created with a method in the server, not a client method. so, the code should be:

```
const bot = new Discord.Client();

function makeChannel(message){
    var server = message.guild;
    var name = message.author.username;

    server.createChannel(name, "text");
}
```

The "text" value is the type of channel you are making. Can be text or voice.

I'll post a link to the most recent documentation for anyone else who encounters this problem [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/general/welcome).

Answer (score 8):

The answer should update documentation link to the `GuildChannelManager` which is now responsible for creating new channel.

(Example from docs)

```js
// Create a new text channel
guild.channels.create('new-general', { reason: 'Needed a cool new channel' })
  .then(console.log)
  .catch(console.error);
```

https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildChannelManager

Answer (score 2):

@Jim Knee's I think your answer is v11, I'm new in discord.js, using Visual Studio Code's auto-code thingy. You can do all the same things except your thing must be this. If you are poor people, getting errors on doing @Jim Knee's answer, this is the place for "YOU!"

Get rid of `server.createChannel(name, "text/voice");`
And get it to THIS `server.channels.create(name, "text/voice");`

Hope I can help at least ;)

I'm just a new guy here too

Answer (score -2):

I think you have not logged in with your bot.

From the [docs](http://discordjs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples.html):

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
var client = new Discord.Client();

client.login('mybot@example.com', 'password', output); // you seem to be missing this

function output(error, token) {
        if (error) {
                console.log(`There was an error logging in: ${error}`);
                return;
        } else
                console.log(`Logged in. Token: ${token}`);
}
```

Alternatively, you can also login with a token instead. See the docs for the example.

Comment: I have logged in with my bot. I just didn't include the login line in the example. As I said, the bot can make and assign roles to users in the server, so it is definitely connected.