# How to create a text channel

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

Recently I have been making a discord bot, and I wanted to make a channel once the players have entered the command `>report [Tag] [Reason]`.

Here are the two methods I have tried (one from a previous StackOverflow question that did not work for me):

```
function makeChannel(message){
    var server = message.guild;
    var name = message.author.username;

    server.createChannel(name, "text");
}
```

Then I tried my own version to see if I could do it:

```
var name = message.author.username;
let reportchannel = server.createChannel(name, "text");

message.createChannel(reportchannel);
```

Yet neither work!

Comment: Can you link the old stackoverflow question you used? Also, are you using a tutorial you could link?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43514065/discord-make-channel-using-bot - Tutorial I used as well as the overflow, just tried to follow this to see if it would help.

Comment: Any error messages? Normally Discord.js should throw an error, especially if you have wrong permissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As seen [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=createChannel) the proper way to create a text channel (and since you're using the message variable I'm going to assume you're in the message event)

```
let name = message.author.username;
message.guild.createChannel(name, 'text')
.then(console.log)
.catch(console.error);
```

Also, another suggestion I have is to use `let` instead of `var` because [this reason](https://medium.com/javascript-scene/javascript-es6-var-let-or-const-ba58b8dcde75)

edit: Just noticed the main reason this isn't working for you is because you're using `message.createChannel()` and note `message.guild.createChannel()`