# Discord bot how to create a private text channel

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm creating a discord bot using node.js and i want it to create a private text channel on a server and add to it the user sending the command "!create" and the bot itself.

I have found a way to make a text channel using this answer: [How to create a text channel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54099201/how-to-create-a-text-channel) 
but i can't find a way to make it private and add people to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do it always like this:

```
const everyoneRole = client.guilds.get('SERVER ID').roles.find('name', '@everyone');

const name = message.author.username;
message.guild.createChannel(name, 'text')
    .then(r => {
        r.overwritePermissions(message.author.id, { VIEW_CHANNEL: true });
        r.overwritePermissions(client.id, { VIEW_CHANNEL: true });
        r.overwritePermissions(everyoneRole, { VIEW_CHANNEL: false });
    })
    .catch(console.error);
```

First, we define the everyoneRole. Then we use the method [`overwritePermissions()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildChannel?scrollTo=overwritePermissions) to overwrite the permissions of the newly created guild textchannel. There we give the message author and the bot the permission to view the channel and we revoke the everyone role the permission to view this channel.

Comment: When i try to run it ,it shows an error on the first line: TypeError: Cannot read property 'roles' of undefined

Comment: You have to enter your serverid in 'SERVER ID' @BenedictDhm

Comment: `client.guilds.get is not a function`

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to @gilles-heinesch for the lead. [The API](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client) of [`discord.js`](https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/) got drastically changed over time, so here is an updated version:

```js
const { Client, Permissions } = require('discord.js');

/** @param {string|number} serverId - a "snowflake" ID you can see in address bar */
async function createPrivateChannel(serverId, channelName) {
  const guild = await client.guilds.fetch(serverId);
  const everyoneRole = guild.roles.everyone;
  const channel = await guild.channels.create(channelName, 'text');
  await channel.overwritePermissions([
    {type: 'member', id: message.author.id, allow: [Permissions.FLAGS.VIEW_CHANNEL]},
    {type: 'member', id: client.user.id, allow: [Permissions.FLAGS.VIEW_CHANNEL]},
    {type: 'role', id: everyoneRole.id, deny: [Permissions.FLAGS.VIEW_CHANNEL]},
  ]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ChannelManager

Use cache collection

```js
const channels = message.guild.channels.cache
const myChannel = channels.find(channel => channel.name === 'channel name')
```