# Discord make channel bot that requires confirmation

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I want the following command `!addclass nameofclass` to send a message to the admin channel asking if we would like to add that class as a channel, listen for `!yes` or `!no`, and if `!yes` create that channel. I'm not sure how `guild.channels.create` is supposed to be used properly. I think I have to define `channels` but I don't know exactly what to define it as.

```js
guild.channels.create({name: newclassname})
               ^    
TypeError: Cannot read property 'create' of undefined
```

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const Client = new Discord.Client();

const token = 'bottoken';

const guild = 'guildToken';

const PREFIX = '!';

Client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log('This Client is online!');
})

const adminchannel = Client.channels.cache.get('adminchanneltoken')

Client.on('message', message => {

    let args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(" ");

    switch (args[0]) {
        case 'addclass':
            const newclassname = args[1];
            if (message.channel.id != 'addclasschanneltoken') {

                Client.channels.cache.get('adminchanneltoken').send('someone wants to add "' + newclassname + '" as a class name')
                Client.channels.cache.get('adminchanneltoken').send('do you want to add it? (yes or no)')

                if (message.channel.id != 'adminchanneltoken') {

                    Client.on('message', message => {

                        let argsrespond = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(" ");

                        switch (argsrespond[0]) {
                            case 'yes':
                                Client.guilds.cache.get('guildToken');
                                Client.channels.cache.get('guildToken');
                                guild.channels.create({
                                        name: newclassname
                                    })
                                    .then(console.log)
                                    .catch(console.error);
                                break;
                            case 'no':
                                break;
                        }
                    })
                } else {}
            } else {}
    }
})

Client.login(token);
```

Comment: how are you getting those so called guild & channel tokens?

Comment: They are copied from the discord app after enabling developer options

Comment: I changed the actual token numbers to those words so I didn't put out private information. The real code uses the token numbers from the discord app.

Comment: They're not called tokens, they're called IDs and it's not important to hide IDs since unless someone is in a guild/channel that has that ID (using a bot or just their own user), they can't find any use out of IDs

Comment: What version of discord.js are you using?

Answer (score 0):

there is an answer to that question already. here is the link:
[How to create a text channel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54099201/how-to-create-a-text-channel)
I hope it's good enough answer to your problem.

Comment: @noam Cohen unless you have an actual answer, not just a redirect to another answer, don't post an answer, just use the comments.

Comment: @Syntle I can't, I dont have enough reputation